# Replace string from column in Python dataframe

Tags: python, excel, regex, dataframe

In reference to: [python replace string in a specific dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42623077/python-replace-string-in-a-specific-dataframe-column)

I'm trying search a column, replace a string and remove a string. Can anyone help?

Example: 0369BODMIN

Replace initial '0' with 'GIF'

Delete anything after the 5th character ([5:])

So it becomes GIF369

Using pandas data-frame and regex.

```
df.loc[df['df'].str.lower().str.startswith('0'), 'CustomerID'] = 
df['CustomerID'].str.extract('(Chaud\w+ )', expand=False)
```

[excel sheet example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REMsn.png)

Edit: My code - modified to loop through the Customer Code column, but when I export the dataframe it only exports the Customer Code column instead of the whole DF.

```
import pandas as pd
customer_data = pd.read_csv(r'C://customers.csv')
customer_data = customer_data['*Customer Code'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('0','GIF',1)[:6])
print(customer_data)
customer_data.to_csv('customersMerged.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow, could you provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your `df`?

Comment: Hey, yes no problem. Although I'm not sure how to produce an example - it's a regex rule I need help with. Will make an edit now.

Comment: Check if the proposed solution works, I didn't use regex patterns tho. For your future reference, a reproducible example is a `code line` that will generate a sample of your `df` so that we can better assist you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it need to be with regex patterns? You could also use the `apply` and `lambda` functions, as below:

The first two lines I'm just generating a `df` with column name `'Customer Code'` and value `'0765POOLE'`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Customer Code'])
df.loc[0,'Customer Code'] = '0765POOLE'
df['Customer Code'] = df['Customer Code'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('0','GIF',1)[:6])
print(df)

Output:
  Customer Code
0        GIF765
```

PLEASE NOTE:

1. This code will replace the first occurrence of a `0` with `GIF` in all values of the `'Customer Code'` column and then slice it to keep only the first 6 characters.

Comment: Thankyou, I've just added the code. Appreciate your help. How do I make it loop through the Customer Code column?

Comment: I have edited my answer. There is no need for a loop. It will apply the lambda function in all values of that column  and replace the first occurrence of a `0` with `GIF`. **EDIT**: don't forget to accept the answer in case it is suitable. ;)

Comment: Thankyou. I've editted my code above - how do I get it to export the whole DF instread of the one column?

Comment: Sorry for that, I have fixed my answer. Also, I see from your code that you forgot the `1` argument from the `replace()` function. This `1` is important as it makes sure you replace only the first occurrence of `0` and not other `0`'s that might exist in your values..

Comment: I mean it goes through the customer code column and applies change, which is great but when i export the dataframe to a csv it only exports the modified customer code column.

I'm trying to export the original dataframe with the customer code editted column into a CSV.

Comment: I have fixed it in my answer.

Comment: sorry, i may have misread - is it fixed to export the whole df, rather than just the column?

Comment: Yes, just check the answer again.

Comment: Just accepted it. This is great- thankyou :)

Comment: Hey @guin0x - I need to modify this code so that it only applied to the '0' at the beginning of the cell. If a cell contains more than one '0', the same rule 'HAL' applies to that '0'. Any idea how I stop it being applied to the 2nd '0'?
<br>
ordersUnleashed['*Customer Code'] = ordersUnleashed['*Customer Code'].apply(lambda a: str(a).replace('0','HAL')[:6])

Comment: Your code is wrong, check again my answer. (Or even your own code in your question). Here you forgot the `1` in `('0',HAL,1)`

Comment: Hey @guinox - apologies, you're right - I missed the '1' out so I corrected that.
The problem I have is if there is more than one '0' in the cell, it will convert both '0's to HAL.

Comment: With this `1` it shouldn't since this is telling the code to replace only the first `0` it finds.

Comment: Ah, ok, is that what the '1' is? Any chance I can take this to chat?